# Does each liquid in a binary mixture boil at its boiling point?

Tags: organic-chemistry, distillation

I have been looking for an explanation and can't seem to find one, so I am asking my question on this forum. I appreciate your responses.

Consider a binary mixture of cyclohexane and toluene (50% mol:50% mol) and I want to separate them with simple distillation or fractional distillation. Each component, as a pure liquid, will boil at its boiling point. However, Raoult's Law shows that each component will have lower vapor pressure when in a mixture. Do cyclohexane and toluene boil at their boiling points or will each component boil at a different temperature? I am not concerned with the boiling point of the mixture, but with the boiling points of each component.

*Cyclohexane has a boiling point of 81 °C*

*Toluene has a boiling point of 111 °C*

Comment: What does the phase diagram look like?

Comment: I was not provided with one. I am in an Organic Chemistry I lab course and the experiment was about separating the binary mixture specified. I was asked to discuss how Raoult's Law and Dalton's Law are relevant to the lab, but I am confused about how those are relevant as the two laws are for mixtures.

Comment: A quick Google will turn up many resources showing the liquid-vapor phase diagram.

Comment: The apparatus that was used had a thermometer measuring the temperature of the vapors. Cyclohexane boiled at 49°C for simple distillation and 
 46°C for fractional distillation. Toluene boiled at 52 °C for simple distillation and 62 °C for fractional distillation.

Comment: From what I can tell, a phase diagram will not be useful as I am not asking for the boiling point of the mixture. I would like to know if each component boils at its respective boiling point or not.

Comment: The pure components boil at their standard boiling point. The mixture boils at some other temperature determined by the composition as can be seen on the phase diagram. So I’m a bit confused on what you are really asking here.

Comment: Does cyclohexane boil at 81 °C and toluene boil at 111 °C in the binary mixture specified? Will at 81°C cyclohexane begin to be collected in the vial? Will at 111 °C toluene begin to be collected in the vial? Or will cyclohexane and toluene boil at different temperatures when in a mixture? This is what I am confused on.

Comment: The _mixture_ boils at the point on the liquidus. Asking what temperature a component of the liquid boils at does not make sense thermodynamically. The solution has a boiling point at that composition, not individual components.

Comment: I'm understanding it better now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> I am not concerned with the boiling point of the mixture, but with the boiling points of each component.

Mixtures don't have a boiling point like pure liquids do. Typically, the composition of the vapor that boils off of a mixture is a mixture of the components as well, but with different composition than the liquid phase. As a consequence, the composition of the liquid phase changes continuously, also changing the temperature at which it boils.

The exception to this general concept is when the composition of the escaping vapor is the same as that of the liquid phase. In that case, you have an azeotrope, and the composition or boiling temperature does not change for the remainder of the distillation (and it is impossible to purify one or the other component by distillation under these circumstances).

> Do cyclohexane and toluene boil at their boiling points or will each component boil at a different temperature?

Whether you can sustain a "rolling boil", i.e. bubbles forming within the liquid phase, depends on the sum of the vapor pressures of the components. This has to be higher (at a given temperature and composition) than the ambient pressure for boiling to occur.

The situation is easier if one of the components is not volatile at all. Confectioners work with sugars dissolved in water, and the boiling temperature increases as water is boiled off. The temperature is used to determine the sugar concentration of the concoction or confection.

Comment: Thank you! Your response was very helpful!